# How to pass typed array as argument in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to pass array typed objects as argument and got errors .

How can i pass 2 objects EmployeeType as an array in mine case ?

```
 1. SELECT employeeTester(row ( row (687678655453,'Yan','Burkov','Yan.Burkov1992@gmail.com','@_+Yan987pl'),row (897689768768,'Ludmila','Burkov','Ludmila.Burkov1967@gmail.com','+_@Ludmia87vb')));
```

> > ERROR: function employeetester(record) does not exist

```
 2. `SELECT employeeTester( row (687678655453,'Yan','Burkov','Yan.Burkov1992@gmail.com','@_+Yan987pl'),row (897689768768,'Ludmila','Burkov','Ludmila.Burkov1967@gmail.com','+_@Ludmia87vb'));`
```

> > ERROR: function employeetester(record, record) does not exist

```
 3. `SELECT employeeTester(ARRAY [row(687678655453,'Yan','Burkov','Yan.Burkov1992@gmail.com','@_+Yan987pl'), row (897689768768,'Ludmila','Burkov','Ludmila.Burkov1967@gmail.com','+_@Ludmia87vb')]);`
```

> > ERROR: function employeetester(record[]) does not exist

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employeeTester(employees EmployeeType[]) RETURNS text [] AS $$

    DECLARE counter SMALLINT = 0; emp EmployeeType; errors text [];


    BEGIN

        FOREACH emp IN ARRAY employees LOOP

                RAISE NOTICE 'Employee data %',emp;

        END LOOP;

        RETURN errors;

    END;


$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Working with one typed object :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employeeTester(employees EmployeeType) RETURNS text [] AS $$

    errors text [];


    BEGIN

        RAISE NOTICE 'Employee id %',employees.emp_id;
        RAISE NOTICE 'Employee FirstName %',employees.firstname;
        RAISE NOTICE 'Employee LastName %',employees.lastname;
        RAISE NOTICE 'Employee Email %',employees.email;
        RAISE NOTICE 'Employee Password %',employees.e_password;

        RETURN errors;

    END;


 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Result :

```
[2018-11-01 08:13:08] [00000] Employee id 687678655453
[2018-11-01 08:13:08] [00000] Employee FirstName Yan
[2018-11-01 08:13:08] [00000] Employee LastName Burkov
[2018-11-01 08:13:08] [00000] Employee Email Yan.Burkov1992@gmail.com
[2018-11-01 08:13:08] [00000] Employee Password @_+Yan987pl
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass Array of record's then call like this.

```
select empTester(ARRAY[row(687678655453,'Yan','Burkov','Yan.Burkov1992@gmail.com','@_+Yan987pl')
 ,row(687678653,'sen','Burkov','Sen.Burkov1992@gmail.com','@_+Sen987pl')]);
```

Comment: what is the error post stack trace after implementing my way